# PowerShell command in batch file where double quotes are required inside the command

Tags: powershell, batch-file

I try to invoke a PowerShell command within a batch file:

```
powershell -Command "(gc test.txt ) -replace ("~\[","`r`n[") | sc test.txt"
```

But it always fails with this error:

```
At line:1 char:29
+ (gc test.txt ) -replace (~\[,`r`n[) | sc test.txt
+                             ~
Missing argument in parameter list.
    + CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (:) [], ParentContainsErrorRecordEx
   ception
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : MissingArgument
```

I try with single quotes for the replace strings:

```
powershell -Command "(gc test.txt ) -replace ('~\[','`r`n[') | sc test.txt"
```

But the backtick escape character is treated like any other text character when it appears within a string enclosed in single quotes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just *escape* the double quotes using a backslash:

```
powershell -Command "(gc test.txt ) -replace (\"~\[\",\"`r`n[\") | sc test.txt"
```

Comment: the single quotes aren't even necessary, escaping the double quotes is sufficient.

Comment: @GeraldSchneider I get an error if I don't put the command in single quotes - don't you?

Comment: I only get the error `ERROR:  Unrecognized command` when I put the command in single quotes.

Comment: @GeraldSchneider You are right, I was testing this within PowerShell... Thanks for the hint.

Comment: powershell -Command "(gc test.txt ) -replace (\"~\[\",\"`r`n[\") | sc test.txt" works. Thank you.